# not using a nas for some years: better way to preserv data

Tags: hard-drive, nas

I have a nas with 2 hd's, it keeps all my data.

I won't use it for a few years, and I want to be sure that all the data are there when I'm going to use it again.

Is it safe to keep it switched off for years? could it be dangerous for the hd's and the data inside them?

Comment: The chances of data surviving any extended period are directly proportional to the number of copies of that data & the locations there are spread to.

Comment: I think this is unanswerable as asked as it depends on the disks and the risk. You may want to add the types of disk, size, RAID configuration and make statements as to acceptable level of risk and value of the data to you.  Chances are very high data will be OK - or at minimum recoverable if you are using RAID1 - but no one will guarantee this.  In other words, its not dangerous, but there is no guarantee either.  Its likely not an important consideration but SSD's are more likely to suffer bit rot then hdd's.  An additional encrypted cloud backup...

Comment: will offer a great deal of protection if that is a practical additional option (provided you can make backups of thr encryption keys).

Comment: How you store the disks likely also can make a significant difference.

Comment: @davidgo - you store the encryption keys to one cloud service on another cloud service, of course ;) tbh, that's the one thing I'm most paranoid about. I have two backups on site, one in the cloud & another with the 'very important' stuff, which includes the keys to the rest.